# Populate Data for TextField on change of LinkField in Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I have a CompositeField consisting of a LinkField and TextField in my dialog.
On select of data for LinkField, I want to populate the TextField also with a value related to the LinkField value.
Any idea how to do this?

This is for Magnolia CMS. I'm using the latest Magnolia version.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ootb binding between different fields.

To create it, you would either need to write your own field that will internally encapsulate the link field and text field and register listener for link field value change and upon change set value for the text field.
Or you would need to rewrite dialog presenter to be able to register such listener on the link field when it's being created.

Sorry, don't have any code samples at the moment to demonstrate it. Hope the explanation is clear enough.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks Jan! :) Actually I have been thinking of these 2 options as well. But for now I will go for listeners first and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to update the text field in view of the editor?

If not, this can be easily achieved by modifying the save action. Your form should have a commit button defined with class=[info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.SaveDialogActionDefinition](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/ui.pub/browse/magnolia-ui-admincentral/src/main/java/info/magnolia/ui/admincentral/dialog/action/SaveDialogActionDefinition.java)

Open SaveDialogActionDefinition and you'll see it points to [info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.SaveDialogAction](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/ui.pub/browse/magnolia-ui-admincentral/src/main/java/info/magnolia/ui/admincentral/dialog/action/SaveDialogAction.java) which, when executed, can manipulate the node before saving the session.

If you extended `SaveDialogAction`, added another method similar to `setNodeName(Node node, JcrNodeAdapter item)` and called it between `setNodeName(...)` and `node.getSession().save()`, you could set any additional property you wanted based on those entered by the user.

You would also need another definition class that referenced your new action so your dialog definition knew to use the new action on commit.

Comment: Yes I need to update the text field in view of the editor. On select of data from linkfield, there will be a default value assigned to the text field that is related to the chosen value of linkfield.  The user can further edit this value.